# Error while inserting a new form piece

Tags: apostrophe-cms

When I try to add data to my form-piece I get the following errors on my network tab and the server terminal. I have attached the screenshots here.
[Network tab error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNAbH.png) [Network tab error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rBY1.png) [Server terminal error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60RcT.png)

This was working a few days back. I'm not sure whats going wrong.

Comment: Hard to know from this .. any way you can share a repo or steps to reproduce locally?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adjusting the piece schema a bit. The **required** fields on the piece schema was causing this problem. Attaching screenshot. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jChFs.png

```
[Required Fields][1]
```

So when I neglect a required field using the show field option inside a piece schema I got this error. ( Form Type A doesn't require email field ). When I remove the required property it works. I don't know if this is a bug or something.

Comment: A required field should be ignored, for "required" purposes, if it is not currently visible according to "showFields". If that is not the case we could investigate to see if a bug has been introduced around that.

Comment: Tom yes the problem arises when I introduce the required property inside the schema. It doesn't happen for widgets but only for pieces.

Comment: bharath OK, if you can supply a minimal apostrophe project that reproduces the issue, such as a fork of github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe-sandbox, we can take a look at it. Would make sense to report that as a github issue on apostrophecms.